# Ant is not following "executable" attribute for javac

Tags: java, bash, build, ant

I've been trying to generate a build using Ant version 1.9.4. I've Java 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 installed on my server. I want to specifically compile my java project against Java 1.6. so, I've included fork = "yes" & executable = "/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/javac"

But, still running ant takes java1.8 for compiling java files. How do ensure that my Ant compiled output is against 1.6.

Note: I've also included source & target as 1.6.

Comment: Don't use `exec` to compile your code. Use the built-in `javac` task. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: Hi CAustin, Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to refer a java compiler (having it in a different directory) than using built-in javac of Ant

Comment: I'm not sure. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The reason being is that I've been facing class file generation issues. I.e for loop in the source code gets converted into while or do /while loops vice versa in the compiled code i.e. .class files. I want to rule out exactly why is my compiler is behaving in such a way.